# Ubuntu mirror hosted on Akamai CDN?

Tags: mirrors

I'm looking for Ubuntu mirror that is hosted on Akamai CDN.

In my country, average Internet speed is 128 kbps. With this speed it is very difficult to update Ubuntu and install software.

However with my ISP I can get high speed (1mbps) speed from CDNs like Akamai.

Earlier, in software sources -> Mirror List -> Select best server, ubuntu.sth.sze.hu was picked. It had worked pretty good.(more than 3 mbps). Now biruni.upm.my/mirror/ubuntu/ is picked. But neither of the mirror has any better speed now.

So I was wondering if there are some mirrors that are hosted on CDNs like Akamai so that I can enter it manually. Or if there are some other tools like "Select best server" so that I can try them as well.

BTW we had local mirror called archive.mitra.net.np/ubuntu, but the company doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I was going to suggest `np.archive.ubuntu.com` but this is limited to 128 Kbps by its owner.

Comment: Yeah, then also its redirected to main canonical servers.

Comment: I suggest to use ubuntu.ntc.net.np with speed of 1mbps. Further information can be found in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/np.archive.ubuntu.com-archive

Comment: Yeah, but this also stopped working.

Comment: akamai ... - isn't it University of Cambridge ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't an Akamai-hosted version of the repos. I think that probably has something to do with the amount they charge and that most mirrors are organised through donated disk space and bandwidth.

You might do well to ask your local Loco what they're using. There is also a Facebook group that should be able to help you out:

- https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ubuntu-Nepal/12277099508

Comment: Yes, the cost of hosting on Akamai makes sense. Never thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regional [Amazon S3 mirrors](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2012/01/regional-s3-backed-ec2-mirrors-available-for-testing/), for Nepal I would give the singapore one a shot:

`http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/`

I don't think they're Akamai based but I know they do some sort of CDN-like things, worth a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.